# How can I print SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL statement that doesnt seem to be working, I've spent over an hour asking how to show what the statement looks like example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=$my_id AND status=$active");
```

Now all I need to do is view what the actual SQL is passed so I imagine it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=2 AND status=4
```

I know this is probably super simple but the keywords im searching is not bringing back the answers, I've tried `print_r`, `echo $result`, `mysql_fetch_array`, etc. and it's not really getting what I need, can someone put me out of misery and tell me how I can get back the hour of my life i just wasted?

Comment: `echo "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=$my_id AND status=$active"`?

Comment: **warning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Thanks guys, im new to php and mysql and this is the basics i learned, so does this mean i have to recode my whole site or is it just where there is MySQL queries, any good resources for a newbie to make this transition and learn about mysqli or PDO and for a newbie which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo it.

```
echo "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=$my_id AND status=$active";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='.is_int($my_id).' AND status='.is_int($active);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
```

Comment: this *may* introduce sql injection attacks.

Comment: yeah, it depends on if the status is a string or int, of cause.
The best thing would be to use pdo and do prepared statements, but it doesn't seem that that's what's beeing used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='.mysqli_escape_string($my_id).' AND status='.mysqli_escape_string($active);
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die mysqli_error()." Query:".$sql;
```

Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because `mysql` is deprecated [Link](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2011/07/25/php-to-deprecate-mysql-extension-in-favor-of-mysqli-and-pdo/).